# Can I float a block of text like an image?

Tags: css

If you change "float:right" to "float:left" in [this W3schools example](http://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_float2), you'll get an image floating to the left of the paragraph.

I want to do the same thing with a block of text.  The purpose is to be able to have little annotations to the left of paragraphs.  If you know of any way to do this, I'd be very grateful.  I'd be really grateful (and amazed) if there were a way to place this annotation midway in a paragraph and have text flow around it.

I've searched all over for an answer but possibly don't know how to ask the question so that search engines can help me.  So now I'm appealing to humans!!

Answer (score 0):

This is the example on the W3schools site adapted for floating text. Changes are on lines 4 and 20.

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
float:right;
border:1px dotted black;
margin:0px 0px 15px 20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p>
In the paragraph below, the image will float to the right. A dotted black border is added to the image.
We have also added margins to the image to push the text away from the image:
0 px margin on the top and right side, 15 px margin on the bottom, and 20 px margin on the left side of the image.
</p>
<p>
<div>This is floated text. This is floated text. This is floated text.</div>
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
This is some text. This is some text. This is some text.
</p>
</body>

</html>
```

You can also use `<div style="float:right">text</div>` if you don't want to float every `div` element.

Edit: To get the floating text halfway down the page, you just stick `<div style="float:right">This is an annotation</div>` right in the middle of the `<p>` block.

Answer (score 0):

Can be done:

```
    #CONTENT .calloutBox{
    background-color:   #1c5a80;
    color:              Black;
    float:              right;
    margin-left:        10px;
    width:              175px;
}
```

And just wrap what you want in <div class="calloutBox">...</div>.